# my images are not showing when i upload them, they apear as placeholders

Tags: migration

the image has a the correct format.

the image url is correct

but some how the image is not showing

this error happened after website was migrated

Please help

[image: preview of error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following things:

1. Please install the [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin and regenerate your thumbnails and check it again.
2. Also check the WordPress Media files type for your WordPress and any other image related (Image Type) plugins installed.
3. WordPress used GD image Library in your Server. Contact your hosting module and check that module is installed and enabled on your server.